# Python Multiline Regex Search in Binary File

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out a way to locate multi-line strings embedded in a binary file. The code I've got will identify non-multi-line versions of the pattern, but not the multi-line versions.

I've tried this with with `re.findall()`:

```
import re
a = open('file', 'rb')
b = a.read()
c = re.findall(b'[<]{2}.*?[>]{2}', b, re.MULTILINE)
```

And with `re.search()`:

```
import re
a = open('file', 'rb')
b = a.read()
c = re.search(b'[<]{2}.*?[>]{2}', b, re.MULTILINE)
c.group()
```

In each case, the code will return non-multi-line substrings, but not those where a `\n` character appears in the string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `re.MULTILINE` with `re.DOTALL`

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` affects the meaning of `^` and `$`, allowing these to anchor linewise rather than stringwise.

Comment: Someone with a background in Ruby?

Comment: The `re.DOTALL` switch did the trick, @Marathon55. Thank you!